# Vim: return to command mode when focus is lost

Tags: vim, macvim

I like my vim to get itself into command mode as often as possible. I think losing focus would be a good event to make that happen. Everything I found is for saving on lost focus.

I'd like it to auto-return to cmd mode when switching tabs in macvim or when cmd+tabbing to another app.

Comment: there's a duplicate question and answer on superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/236534/change-to-normal-mode-when-macvim-goes-background

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following [autocommand](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.3) would be the "obvious" choice.

```
au FocusLost,TabLeave * stopinsert
```

Unfortunately, it only seems to be working properly for TabLeave.  The FocusLost event is triggering but for some reason the [stopinsert](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:stopinsert) command isn't actually taking effect until after a key event is received once Vim has regained focus.

Instead, you can take advantage of [feedkeys](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.txt#feedkeys()) and the "Get me to normal mode no matter what!" [key combo](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.txt#CTRL-\_CTRL-N):

```
au FocusLost,TabLeave * call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>")
```

The only downside is that `feedkeys()` requires at least Vim 7.  This shouldn't be a big deal, though, since Vim 7 was released back in 2006.

Comment: Cool- never knew about `Ctrl-\_Ctrl-N`.  I had the stopinsert line in my vimrc but always was bugged by the fact that it took one more character when returning to the buffer...:wq

Comment: I would have commented, but my comment comes with formatting.  See below.  :)  I must thank @jamessan for guidance on this.

Answer (score 7):

I would have added a comment, but I can't format the solution.

The feedkeys solution is great, with the small hitch that it ALWAYS goes back to normal mode, regardless of what other mode you were in.  I don't want to cancel command line mode (for drag&drop files in Windows) and I don't need to cancel visual mode, I just wanted to cancel insert mode.

The solution, then, appears as:

```
autocmd FocusLost * call PopOutOfInsertMode()

function! PopOutOfInsertMode()
    if v:insertmode
        feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>")
    endif
endfunction
```

In other words, only pop out if you're in an insert mode.  This could be further refined, since v:insertmode will be 'i' in "normal insert", 'r' in Replace mode, and 'v' in Virtual Replace mode.  For me, popping out regardless is good, but the user may want to edit to suit.

If this isn't working for you in MacVim, replace the contents of `PopOutOfInsertMode` with:

```
if v:insertmode == 'i' | call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>") | endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! I discovered the same problem with the original solution. Tabbing away while in command mode to look something up then coming back and finding it cleared was frustrating.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in MacVim.  I haven't looked into why, though it's on the list of things to do.  :)

Comment: I installed the latest (7.3) MacVim and the problem seems to be fixed.  ...although I haven't used it a ton and I'm not positive, but I think it's working now.

Comment: I'm on MacVim snapshot 62 (the latest for OSX 10.6 AFAIK) and it doesn't seem to work, no idea why. The top answer works fine, however.

Comment: `if v:insertmode == 'i' | call feedkeys("\<C-\>\<C-n>") | endif` seems to work for me on MacVim.